# warning:initialization from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, gcc

I do not understand where the error.
why this error message:
initialization from incompatible pointer type.
Help me please, friends.

```
const struct _displayout_default
{
const char* length;
const char**  buf;

}DisplayOut_DEFAULT[2] =  
{
    {
    "02", 
    (const char*[]){
        "01",
        "02",
        "03",
        "04"
        }
    },
    {
    "02", 
    (const char*[]){
        "01",
        "02",
        "03",
        "04"
        }
    }
};
```

#### Update:

MPLAB® C Compiler
For PIC32 MCUs

C Standards Information
  American National Standard for Information Systems – Programming Language – C.
  American National Standards Institute (ANSI), 11 West 42nd. Street, New York,
  New York, 10036.

GCC Documents
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/
http://sourceware.org/binutils/

Compiler options:
  -g -mlong-calls -DNDEBUG -Os

Comment: [`Please provide a short but complete example which demonstrates the problem`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22762/159703); specify compiler version, options and invocation.

Comment: mmm. unable to reproduce that. Can you post a true [SSCCE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions) or find out the environmental difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit** (old answer gone)

Unfortunately, I'm not able to reproduce the message with the same Compiler and same options:

```
T:\>"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\mplabc32\v2.01\bin\pic32-gcc.exe" -g -mlong-calls -DNDEBUG -Os test.c
```

No Errors.

Likewise with `pic32mx-gcc-4.5.1.exe` - No Errors.

---

#### *Details*:

Source

```
const struct _displayout_default
{
    const char* length;
    const char**  buf;

}DisplayOut_DEFAULT[2] =  
{
    {
        "02", 
        (const char*[]){
            "01",
            "02",
            "03",
            "04"
        }
    },
    {
        "02", 
        (const char*[]){
            "01",
            "02",
            "03",
            "04"
        }
    }
};    

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{

    return 0;
}
```

Compiler version:

- downloaded: **[mplabc32_v2_01_windows_installer.exe](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/mplabc32_v2_01_windows_installer.exe)** **148Mb !!**
- version:

  ```
  T:\>"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\mplabc32\v2.01\bin\pic32-gcc.exe" -v
  ```

```
    pic32-gcc.exe: 2: No such file or directory
    Using built-in specs.
    COLLECT_GCC=c:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\mplabc32\v2.01\bin\pic32-gcc.exe
    COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/program files
    (x86)/microchip/mplabc32/v2.01/bin/../pic32mx/bin/gcc/pic32mx/4.5.1/lto-wrapper.exeTarget:
    pic32mxConfigured with: ../../src45x/gcc/configure --build=i386-pc-linux-gnu
    --host=i586-mingw32msvc --target=pic32mx --disable-threads --disable-libmudflap
    --disable-libssp --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-hosted-libstdcxx
    --with-arch=pic32mx --enable-sgxx-sde-multilibs --disable-threads --with-gnu-as
    --with-gnu-ld --disable-sim --disable-bootstrap --enable-obsolete
    --disable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libfortran --enable-languages=c
    --disable-shared --with-newlib --disable-nls
    --prefix=/home/c11067/work/C32/builds/pic32-microchip-release-2.01-freeze-20110726/pic32-tools
    --disable-libgomp --without-headers --disable-libffi --enable-gofast
    --enable-poison-system-directories --program-prefix=pic32-
    --libexecdir=/home/c11067/work/C32/builds/pic32-microchip-release-2.01-freeze-20110726/pic32-tools/pic32mx/bin
    --with-dwarf2 --with-host-libstdcxx='-static-libgcc
    -Wl,-Bstatic,-lstdc++,-Bdynamic -lm'
    --with-libelf=/home/c11067/work/C32/builds/pic32-microchip-release-2.01-freeze-20110726/canadian-cross-build/mingw32-libs
    --enable-lto
    --with-gmp=/home/c11067/work/C32/builds/pic32-microchip-release-2.01-freeze-20110726/canadian-cross-build/mingw32-libs
    --with-ppl=/home/c11067/work/C32/builds/pic32-microchip-release-2.01-freeze-20110726/canadian-cross-build/mingw32-libs
    --with-cloog=/home/c11067/work/C32/builds/pic32-microchip-release-2.01-freeze-20110726/canadian-cross-build/mingw32-libs
    --with-zlib=/home/c11067/work/C32/builds/pic32-microchip-release-2.01-freeze-20110726/canadian-cross-build/mingw32-libs
    --with-bugurl=http://www.microchip.com/supportThread model: singlegcc version
    4.5.1 MPLAB C Compiler for PIC32 MCUs v2.01-20110816 (Microchip Technology)
```

Comment: I just noticed this too... and was verifying it when you posted this.

Comment: It was Cyrillic. Russian letter C and English letter C coincide on the keyboard. Several years ago I was looking for such a bug for several hours... @АлександрКуркин Maybe you should look at other occurrences of Cyryllic letters.

Comment: @АлександрКуркин checkout my updated answer. Perhaps I'm using a nwever version?

Comment: @sehe thank you for the trouble. I use the same version of the compiler  pic32mx-gcc-4.5.1.exe

Comment: @savva: nope, no warnings. I showed the command lines used. Perhaps the code has more to it in your actual test case? Perhaps you could post it (http://pastebin.com or http://gist.github.com)

Comment: @savva: with `-Wall -pedantic` I can get it to emit 'warning: ISO C90 forbids compound literals` twice...

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with your code, and it doesn't give any warnings with gcc 4.4.5 or clang 1.1.